# Unable to load consul config

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, spring-cloud, consul

I'm trying to build sample microservice app using this tutorial [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdcnpD-GpZ4&t=495s). jhipster v5.2.1  So I've created a gateway and an armory started consul using this command:

**docker-compose -f src/main/docker/consul.yml up**

While I've pointed into the armory folder writing this command :

***./gradlew***

I got this error :

```
2018-09-03 13:20:11.235  WARN 7224 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.c.c.ConsulPropertySourceLocator    : Unable to load consul config from config/armory-swagger/

com.ecwid.consul.transport.TransportException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8600 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
```

Could you please help me

Comment: Are you able to access consul from your browser? at http://localhost:8500

Comment: Actually I can't

Comment: I'm working with a  windows machine 8.1, I've installed docker toolbox, I tried to change the port 8500, although it's not occupied, I failed to run the application too. thank you for  your response

Comment: @GaëlMarziou    I've enabled the port 8500 using firewall advanced settings but  I  still have the same  issue while  connecting  to localhost:8500 (This site can’t be reached), and although I got this  message into my console  ' Newer Consul version available: 1.2.2 (currently running: 1.2.0)'  I can't reach the page

Comment: Have you tried running Consul outside Docker? It's easy as it's a single binary. I suspect something specific to your environment so I guess I won't be able to help here.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou, Honestly no, As I wrote in the post description above, I'm following the tutorial, In order to install a complete  jhipster app, and  implement jhipster console to get an overview of  its features and create  a similar concept of  monitoring, by the way thank  you for  your  helps

Comment: Well this tutorial is a bit outdated and it does not give you any information about why you do things (see official doc for this, https://www.jhipster.tech/microservices-architecture/). You are starting with a very complex setup, there are too many moving parts.

Comment: I recommend you ask questions on our gitter forum https://gitter.im/jhipster/generator-jhipster

Comment: factually I'm attached to its  concept  thus, I struggled  to found a solution to run it, although it's outdated as  you said, I  hope  that I found the same concept with the new version and updated

Comment: @GaëlMarziou thanks  for  the  link

Comment: Sorry It typed the wrong port, are you able to access http://localhost:8500/ui/#/dc1/kv/config/ in browser? I'm on Windows 10 and this works fine but on Windows 8.1 it's another version of Docker.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou  Unfrontally No

Comment: If you are using the toolbox you have to replace localhost by the IP of your Docker machine vm. You will have to ajust the bootstrap.yml properties to point to this adress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the toolbox you have to replace localhost by the IP of your Docker machine vm. You will have to ajust the bootstrap.yml properties to point to this adress.

You should also be able to apply this trick : https://www.jhipster.tech/tips/020_tip_using_docker_containers_as_localhost_on_mac_and_windows.html

Answer (score 0):

I just changed fail-fast to false in bootstrap-prod.yml
You can disable Spring Cloud Config this way.

```
    fail-fast: false
```

Otherwise you have to provide proper configuration as stated above.

Or you can run this command if you have already installed consul on your development machine.

```
    consul agent -dev
```